# How to get bluetooth device mac address in IOS 9.0 or higher version?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

I tried to find it in `CBCentralManager` or `CBPeripheral`, but I can't find any information about mac address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Mac Address From CBPeripheral And CBCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145798/how-to-get-mac-address-from-cbperipheral-and-cbcenter)